# ASP.Net validator styling

Tags: asp.net, .net, css, validation

I have multiple validators on a textbox (see structure below). When the RequiredFieldValidator passes but the CustomValidator fails there is a gap between the Textbox and the CustomValidator as the RequiredsFieldValidator has a Hidden CSS property.

```
[FieldLabel] [TextBox] [RequiredFieldValidator] [CustomValidator]
```

The HTML output from the validators can be seen below.

```
<input name="...Age" value="65" id="...Age" type="text">
<span id="...RequiredFieldValidator" style="color: rgb(195, 1, 185); visibility: hidden;">required</span>
<span id="...CustomValidator" style="color: rgb(195, 1, 185); visibility: visible;">must be between 55 and 74</span>
```

How can I make sure there is no space between the textbox and CustomValidator?

Answer (score 2):

set  `Display="Dynamic"` property of Validator

[MSDN: ASP.NET Validation in Depth](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479045.aspx)